# Split [C#-MySQL] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, tag-disambiguation

I found [c#-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-mysql) with 4 questions in this community!

I think it should burninated.

Comment: Yet another burnination request that could have been fulfilled by the requester itself.

Comment: Any specific reason for asking the community? In the [recently adjusted burnination guideline](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination), you may burn tags yourself if you're knowledgable on the topic and have conferred with at least one other member, and the tag has less than 50 questions. If you want to confer with trusted users, you can use a chat room, like [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth That is first time that I see a tag of multiple tags! I just thought it should burninated! but I'm not sure! Is it always a [burninate-request] for these kind of tags?

Comment: Well, if you're unsure and want feedback, a question is fine. I'm very pro-burning this tag down (since I don't see how C# and MySQL are more related than C# and any other database), so it seems open and shut to me, but let's see what other community members have to say about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, this is a reasonable request. The tag has no cause to exist. Separate [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) and [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) tags already exist and are more flexible. There's no need for a combined tag.

Half of the questions with the tag were completely unsalvageable (*i.e.*, debug my code with no code) and needed to be removed, so I did that first.

That left two, which I edited and retagged:

- [How can I get MySQL cell value by column name in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39882024/how-can-i-get-mysql-cell-value-by-column-name-in-c)
- [Transferring Excel data into SQL table with different columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41271458/transferring-excel-data-into-sql-table-with-different-columns)

As mentioned in the comments, since this tag only had a very small number of questions (4), it's reasonable for a single person who knows what they're doing to remove it. There's no need for [the formal burnination process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination). Of course, if you're unsure, it's always fair to bring it up on Meta to get some advice.

Note that, even when you're doing *ad hoc* burninations, it's still important that you do more than simply remove the tag from questions. I closed and/or deleted the problematic questions (having a diamond helps, but even casting a vote is sufficient—just don't remove the tag from the question until it's been handled by other community members), and while I was editing to retag the ones that were worth keeping around, I also fixed other obvious problems with the questions. If you simply go around and remove the tag, we lose the ability to clean up the questions while they're all findable in one search query.